# GTA V mapp mi numbers

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I was just wondering what the little 'mi' numbers stood for on the map? They come up when driving and I've always wondered whether or not it mean't miles or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does show you the distance in miles to your selected target.